# How to use booktabs for complex multicols tables to remain consistent design

Tags: multicolumn, booktabs

I am new to latex and booktabs but love the design of booktabs compared to "normal" tables.
Thus, I want to use booktabs and have finished some simple tables such as an overview of demographics.

However, I need to create a quite complex table with several multicolumns to compare the grouping of multiple authors. The table should look like this (including more authors of course):

[image: Exemplary table. Note: A, B, C.. are not the same words but just fill the gaps]

However, the basic principle of booktabs, as I understood, is that one uses as few vertical and horizontal lines as possible. However, these are needed here for the demarcation in any case.

Would you still use so many lines, although this is then considered inconsistent compared to the other tables, or should I move away from booktabs because of this?

Would be very happy to hear your opinions. Thanks in advance!

Edit:
MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{adjustbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{landscape}
\begin{table}[]
\adjustbox{max width=\linewidth}{%
\begin{tabular}{@{}lcccccc@{}}
\toprule
 & \multicolumn{2}{l}{\textbf{A1}} & \multicolumn{2}{l}{\textbf{A2}} & \multicolumn{2}{l}{A3} \\ \midrule
\multirow{12}{*}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Production\\ planning\end{tabular}} & Sales   planning & \multirow{3}{*}{} & \multirow{3}{*}{Program planning} & Sales forecast & \multirow{3}{*}{Primary Requirements   Planning} & \multirow{3}{*}{Production program planning} \\ \cmidrule(lr){2-2} \cmidrule(lr){5-5}
 & \multirow{2}{*}{Production   program planning} &  &  & \multirow{2}{*}{Rough-cut scheduling} &  &  \\
 &  &  &  &  &  &  \\ \cmidrule(l){2-7} 
 & \multirow{4}{*}{Inventory   planning} & \multirow{3}{*}{Production requirements   planning} & \multirow{4}{*}{Material management} & Bill of material   explosion & \multirow{4}{*}{Material Requirements   Planning} & Bill of material   explosion \\ \cmidrule(lr){5-5} \cmidrule(l){7-7} 
 &  &  &  & \multirow{2}{*}{Inventory   reconciliation} &  & Gross requirements   planning \\ \cmidrule(l){7-7} 
 &  &  &  &  &  & Net requirements planning \\ \cmidrule(lr){3-3} \cmidrule(lr){5-5} \cmidrule(l){7-7} 
 &  & Procurement type allocation &  & Lot size calculation &  & Lot Size calculation \\ \cmidrule(l){2-7} 
 & \multirow{5}{*}{Production planning} & Work preparation & \multirow{5}{*}{Time management} & \multirow{2}{*}{Scheduling} & \multirow{2}{*}{Rough-cut scheduling} &  \\ \cmidrule(lr){3-3}
 &  & Production order scheduling &  &  &  &  \\ \cmidrule(lr){3-3} \cmidrule(l){5-7} 
 &  & Lot Size calculation &  & \multirow{3}{*}{Capacity planning} & \multirow{3}{*}{Capacity alignment} & \multirow{3}{*}{Detailed scheduling} \\ \cmidrule(lr){3-3}
 &  & \multirow{2}{*}{Capacity planning} &  &  &  &  \\
 &  &  &  &  &  &  \\ \midrule
\multirow{5}{*}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Production\\ control\end{tabular}} & \multirow{5}{*}{Production control} & Sequencing & \multirow{5}{*}{Sequencing} & \multirow{3}{*}{Order release} & \multirow{3}{*}{Shop-floor control} & Sequencing \\ \cmidrule(lr){3-3} \cmidrule(l){7-7} 
 &  & \multirow{2}{*}{Order release} &  &  &  & \multirow{2}{*}{Order release} \\
 &  &  &  &  &  &  \\ \cmidrule(lr){3-3} \cmidrule(l){5-7} 
 &  & Order monitoring &  & \multirow{2}{*}{Order monitoring} & \multirow{2}{*}{Order monitoring} &  \\ \cmidrule(lr){3-3}
 &  & Resource monitoring &  &  &  & \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular}%
}
\end{table}
\end{landscape}

\end{document}
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!  Since you mention "one uses as few vertical and horizontal lines as possible": Horizontal lines from the `booktabs` package are designed to be used in tables without any vertical lines and the `booktabs` manual explicitly states "Never, ever use vertical rules." and "You should not use vertical rules in tables, end of story."

Comment: Did you already try to produce a table similar to the one shown in your image using lines from the `booktabs` package? If so, please share what you tried and specify what you do not like about the output.

Comment: Depending on what kind of information the placeholders "A", "B",... represent, it might be better to use an entirely different way of presenting this information. Probably some sort of graph or timeline-like structure would work here?

Comment: Thank you very mich for your fast responses! 
I tried creating it using booktabs. It looks (using adjustbox for now) this: https://prnt.sc/1554b59

Some details like centralizing the authors would make it look better, but the amount of separated horizontal lines makes it quite difficult to understand compared to the "excel table" from above. 

The table is about comparing how different authors differentiate between tasks and how they name them, thus a table is a good fit imo.

Comment: Please add the image of your output as well as a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) showing how you produced it directly into your question.

Comment: As far as I can tell, each "Author" corresponds to two individual table columns. How are these two columns related? does the second one contains more specific points (subitems or something similar) in comparison to the first column?

Comment: I have uploaded the MWE & Output. Yes, exactly! In total, I want to compare 5 authors each with two columns.

Comment: A precise heading for the respective columns would also be useful, you're right.

Comment: firstly never scale tables `\adjustbox{max width=\linewidth}{%` means you have no chance of having consistent font sizes or rule widths with the rest of the document.

Comment: What about a more graphic-like layout, such as this one based on rounded boxes:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/0OXmt.png This should look different enough from your regular `booktabs`-based tables and more like a graphic, so you could be able to prevent the inconsistent tables issue you mentioned in your question.

Comment: You're totally right David. I just wanted to finish the basic concept before going to the next challenge which will be scaling/fitting. 

Great idea, leandriis! Thanks a lot. How did you manage to create such a graphic? What library should I use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code for the suggested alternative layout based on rounded rectangles:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{pdflscape}

\newcommand{\mybox}[2]{\Block[draw,rounded-corners=6pt]{#1-1}{#2}}

\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}
\centering
\NiceMatrixOptions{cell-space-limits = 1.5pt}
\footnotesize
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{2.15pt}
\begin{NiceTabular}{lwc{0pt} cc wc{0pt} cc wc{0pt} cc wc{0pt} cc wc{0pt} cc}
  && \Block[draw]{1-2}{Author1} &    
  && \Block[draw]{1-2}{Author2} &    
  && \Block[draw]{1-2}{Author3} &
  && \Block[draw]{1-2}{Author4} &    
  && \Block[draw]{1-2}{Author5} &\\
\\
\Block[draw]{12-1}{\rotate Production planning} 
  && \mybox{1}{Sales\\ Planning} &  
  && \mybox{2}{Program\\ planning} & \mybox{1}{Sales\\ forecast} 
  && \mybox{2}{Primary\\ requirements\\ planning} & \mybox{2}{Production\\ Program\\ Planning}
  && \mybox{2}{Program\\ planning} & \mybox{1}{Sales\\ forecast} 
  && \mybox{2}{Primary\\ requirements\\ planning} & \mybox{2}{Production\\ Program\\ Planning} \\ 

  && \mybox{1}{Production\\  program\\ planning} & 
  && & \mybox{1}{Rough-cut\\ scheduling} 
  && &    
  && & \mybox{1}{Rough-cut\\ scheduling} 
  && &    \\
\\
  && \mybox{4}{Inventory\\ planning} & \mybox{3}{Production\\ requirement\\ planning} 
  && \mybox{4}{Material\\management} & \mybox{1}{Bill of \\ material\\ explosion} 
  && \mybox{4}{Material \\ Requirements \\ Planning} & \mybox{1}{Bill of \\ material\\ explosion} 
  && \mybox{4}{Material\\management} & \mybox{1}{Bill of \\ material\\ explosion} 
  && \mybox{4}{Material \\ Requirements \\ Planning} & \mybox{1}{Bill of \\ material\\ explosion} \\
  
  && & 
  && & \mybox{2}{Inventory \\ reconciliation} 
  && & \mybox{1}{Gross \\ requirements\\ panning}
  && & \mybox{2}{Inventory \\ reconciliation} 
  && & \mybox{1}{Gross \\ requirements\\ panning}\\
  
  && & 
  && & 
  && & \mybox{1}{Net \\ requirements\\ panning}
  && & 
  && & \mybox{1}{Net \\ requirements\\ panning}\\
  
  && & \mybox{1}{Production\\ type\\ allocation} 
  && & \mybox{1}{Lot size \\ calculation} 
  &&  & \mybox{1}{Lot size \\ calculation} 
  && & \mybox{1}{Lot size \\ calculation} 
  &&  & \mybox{1}{Lot size \\ calculation} \\
\\
  && \mybox{4}{Production\\ planning} & \mybox{1}{Work\\ preparation} 
  && \mybox{4}{Time\\ management} & \mybox{2}{Scheduling} 
  && \mybox{2}{Rough-cut\\ scheduling} & 
  && \mybox{4}{Time\\ management} & \mybox{2}{Scheduling} 
  && \mybox{2}{Rough-cut\\ scheduling} & \\
  
  &&  & \mybox{1}{Production\\ order\\ scheduling} 
  &&  &  
  &&  & 
  &&  &  
  &&  & \\
  
  &&  & \mybox{1}{Lot Size \\ calculation} 
  &&  & \mybox{2}{Capacity\\ planning} 
  && \mybox{2}{Capacity\\ alignment} & \mybox{2}{Detailed\\ scheduling}
  &&  & \mybox{2}{Capacity\\ planning} 
  && \mybox{2}{Capacity\\ alignment} & \mybox{2}{Detailed\\ scheduling}\\
  
  &&  & \mybox{1}{Capacity\\ planning} 
  &&  &  
  &&  & 
  &&  &  
  &&  & \\
  
\\
\Block[draw]{4-1}{\rotate Production control} 
  && \mybox{4}{Production\\ control} & \mybox{1}{Sequencing} 
  && \mybox{4}{Sequencing} & \mybox{2}{Order\\ release} 
  && \mybox{2}{Shop-floor\\ control} & \mybox{1}{Sequencing}  
  && \mybox{4}{Sequencing} & \mybox{2}{Order\\ release} 
  && \mybox{2}{Shop-floor\\ control} & \mybox{1}{Sequencing}  \\
  
  &&  & \mybox{1}{Order\\ release} 
  &&  &  
  &&  & \mybox{1}{Order\\ release}
  &&  &  
  &&  & \mybox{1}{Order\\ release}\\
  
  &&  & \mybox{1}{Order\\ monitoring} 
  &&  & \mybox{2}{Order\\ monitoring} 
  && &\mybox{2}{Order\\ monitoring}  
  &&  & \mybox{2}{Order\\ monitoring} 
  && &\mybox{2}{Order\\ monitoring}  \\
  
  &&  & \mybox{1}{Resource\\ monitoring} 
  &&  &  
  &&  & 
  &&  &  
  &&  & \\
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{landscape}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I will try to out. :)

Comment: I have one follow-up. I have added all my data and changed some details. Thus, it should be completed. However, it is too wide, (longer than the page's width). All I read about on this forum is adjust box/resize or some fancy "redesigning" of the table. Could you share please with me your best practices in this context?

Comment: That depends on how much too wide the table now is. You could play around with adding linebreaks inside of lenghtier words, such as "management". Alternatively, reduce the font size from `\footnotesize` to `\scriptsize`. You could also locally decrease the margin sized for this particular page only. Which method to choose is hard to tell without knowing how wide your table actually is.

Comment: Resizing a table using `resizebox`, `scalebox` or `adjustbox` is  nefinitely not the best method as this will lead to inconsistent font sizes throughout the document.

Comment: Thanks! I will try out. The table is too long, not too wide. But I will deal with it. 
nicematrix is really nice and quite handy, will definitely use it in the future as well.

Comment: In your previous comment you stated your table was too wide, hence I added some suggestions on how to make your table narrower. If your table is too tall for the available space, you could try to remove or alter the cell-space-limits value in order to save some space.

Comment: Thanks! I am so sorry for wasting your time, but sadly some questions raised I wasn't able to answer by myself. The authors will by cited by \cite, but then the name does not fit in the box anymore and its does not adjust. How can I manually adjust the box size accordingly? And second, to save some space, I want to decrease the space between each box e.g. between the last box in production planning and the first in production controlling. But I cant figure out how to archive it. But I also understand if you are getting tired of this! Either way, thank you very much

Comment: Regarding the width of author names: You could try to enclose the `\cite` command in a `\parbox` of wuitable width. Something like `\Block[draw]{1-2}{\parbox{2cm}{\centering longer author name here}}` should automatically wrap the contents into two lines.

Comment: Regarding the vertical white spaces between sets of boxes: They are caused by an empty table row. To get rid of them, replace `\\ \\ ` with a single `\\ `. Be aware though, that this affects the required value of the `\mybox` commands in the first column.